# "E:Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list (type),"

Tags: apt

I want to update Ubuntu, but I see this message:

```
E:Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
(type),
E:The list of sources could not be read.,
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you need to provide file /et/capt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list

Comment: The first line of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list` contains an error so the package manager can't understand it. If you can't fix this yourself please edit your question an include at least the first few lines of that file. The file name suggest that the file contains package sources from Medibuntu. As the Medibuntu repositories don't exist any more you may want to just remove the file.

Answer (score 7):

Just remove the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list` file. Medibuntu is a dead project anyways:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
```